# How to split alphanumeric string but keep last alpha value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had a question regarding splitting alphanumeric characters. Say I have an array that looks like the following:

```
var arr = ["Z100X", "RT540X", "3001X", "YRT560X"];
```

How do I split the characters in this array so that the array ends up like this:

```
var arr = ["Z", "100X", "RT", "540X", "3001X", "YRT", "560X"]
```

I was thinking about using a general expression like this

```
arr.replace(/[\d]+/, ","+/[\d]+/);
```

But not sure how to keep the "X" character at the end attached to the number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What is `"," + /[\d]+/` supposed to mean? It makes no sense to concatenate a string to a regular expression, and why would you use it in the replacement string?

Comment: You can't use `.replace()` to turn one array element into two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.toString()`, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[A-Z]+|\d+[A-Z]+/g` to match one or more A-Z or one or more digits followed by one or more A-Z.

The `RegExp` is intended to match for example `"Z"` or `"RT"` or `"YRT"` : `[A-Z]+`, or, `"100X"` or `"3001X"` : `\d+[A-Z]+`; the `g` flag is for purpose of returning all matches found.

```js
var arr = ["Z100X", "RT540X", "3001X", "YRT560X"];
var res = arr.toString().match(/[A-Z]+|\d+[A-Z]+/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Bravo, KISS wins.

Comment: Would be useful to explain the regex, perhaps use `join` for clarity (since that's what `toString`) does, but *impressive*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Included description of `RegExp` at Answer

Comment: The added explanation just says what the regex is, not *why* it works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did not consider using `.join()`.What would be passed to `.join()`? Tried without parameter passed and both `""` and `" "`, did not appear to return expected result

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not sure gather what you mean by _"why it works"_?

Comment: Exactly that: What's the process, the steps the values go through. It's a great solution, deserves a solid explanation.

Comment: This worked perfectly and thanks for the explanation! Simple and concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` with a regex matching [a bunch of letters] followed by [any non-empty String]:

```js
var arr = ["Z100X", "RT540X", "3001X", "YRT560X"],
    arr2 = [];

for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
  var parts = arr[i].split(/([A-Z]+)(.+)/).filter(Boolean);
  arr2.push.apply(arr2, parts);
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Here, `.filter(Boolean)` is used to remove empty Strings from the Array.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, I am not used to `apply`, I did not know it could do this. I changed it!

Answer (score 1):

You may also do as follows;

```js
var arr = ["Z100X", "RT540X", "3001X", "YRT560X"],
result  = arr.reduce((r,s) => r.concat(s.match(/[A-Z]+|\w+/g)),[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

- symbole is not required at the end of Regex. It is like alpha or alphabet which starts with digits.

```js
var arr = ["Z100X", "RT540X", "3001X", "YRT560X"];
var res = arr.toString().match(/[A-Z]+|\d+[A-Z]/g);
console.log(res);
```